# Magento - Added Tab gives Option menu to include closing ul and div

Tags: html, magento, menu, product, erp

I added a new tab into the Magento admin at Product Management to view ERP data. Added the following files:

```
class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Erp extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setProduct($this->getProduct());
        $this->setTemplate('Purchase/Product/Edit/Tab/SupplyNeedsSummary.phtml');
    }

    /**
    * Return current product instance
    *
    * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Product
    */

    public function getProduct()
    {
        return Mage::registry('product');
    }
}
```

and...

```
class MDN_AdvancedStock_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Erp extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Erp {

    protected function _toHtml() {
            return parent::_toHtml();
    }

}
```

I edited file Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tabs and added in (around line #85):

```
$this->addTab('erp', array(
   'label'     => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('ERP Samenvatting'),
   'content'   => $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/catalog_product_edit_tab_erp')->toHtml(),
   ));
```

It all works fine, data is showing. However, the HTML of the tabs menu is now screwed up for some reason. When I look into the source code this is what I see:

```
    <li>

        <a class="tab-item-link" title="Voorraad" name="inventory" id="product_info_tabs_inventory" href="#">
            <span><span title="The information in this tab has been changed." class="changed"/><span title="This tab contains invalid data. Please solve the problem before saving." class="error"/>Voorraad</span>
        </a>

    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="tab-item-link active" title="ERP Samenvatting" name="erp" id="product_info_tabs_erp" href="#">
            <span><span title="The information in this tab has been changed." class="changed"/><span title="This tab contains invalid data. Please solve the problem before saving." class="error"/>ERP Samenvatting</span>

        </a>
        </li></ul></div>

    <li>
        <a class="tab-item-link ajax notloaded" title="Categorieën" name="categories" id="product_info_tabs_categories" href="http://www.sicomputers.nl/index.php/login/catalog_product/categories/id/23532/key/3fd54077f0c85aa69c3383ccb4f0e7cb/">
            <span><span title="The information in this tab has been changed." class="changed"/><span title="This tab contains invalid data. Please solve the problem before saving." class="error"/>Categorieën</span>
        </a>
        <div style="display: none;" id="product_info_tabs_categories_content"/>
    </li>
```

As you can see, at the ERP option, a closing UL and DIV are included for some reason. Does anyone know WHY this is happening. Please note that all the changes I made are mentioned in this post. No other changes have been made.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Do no edit core files. To add new tab you should use layout updates. See how it is done for bundle products:

```
<adminhtml_catalog_product_bundle>
    <reference name="product_tabs">
        <action method="addTab"><name>bundle_items</name><block>bundle/adminhtml_catalog_product_edit_tab_bundle</block></action>
        <action method="bindShadowTabs"><first>bundle_items</first><second>customer_options</second></action>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_catalog_product_bundle>
```